# Link of a face in an abstract simplicial complex

Tags: general-topology, simplex, simplicial-complex

I don't really understand this definition (from [here](http://www0.maths.ox.ac.uk/system/files/coursematerial/2015/984/107/toplectnotes14-revised.pdf)):

[image]

Ok, so we're considering a face $v$ (as $K$ is a simplicial complex, vertices are faces). I get that the vertex set of $\text{lk}(v)$ is the set of vertices which are adjacent to $v$. What I don't understand is why the edges between them are the link's simplices. How is the union between one of those edges and $v$ in $\Sigma$?

Also, not sure I understand the idea behind the star. Wouldn't the union of all the triangles also be in $\Sigma$? If so, then wouldn't the union of the insides of simplices containing $v$ be much bigger?

Comment: It's not that for some $\sigma$, $\sigma\cup\{v\}$ will necessarily be in $\Sigma$. What the definition is saying is we want to gather all $\sigma$ such that $\sigma\cup\{v\}\ is$ in $\Sigma$. Also, it is more than just edges as $\sigma$ is a subset of the vertex set. Look at example 4.7 for what potential $\sigma$ could be.

Comment: And for the star of a vertex, the union is not of $\sigma$s, but of $\operatorname{inside}(\sigma)$. The inside of $\sigma\in\Sigma$ is defined in Def 4.2. Note that it is a different definition to the inside of a set in the rest of the notes.

Comment: From what I remember of this course, at the end it hides some of the more technical details away in lieu of a more heuristic approach. It only lightly goes over that when working with $|K|$ for $K=(V,\Sigma)$ you are working with a a quotient of a large, messy product of simplices. One of the problemsheet questions was tricky as you have to work with fattening specific sets, and it's hard to keep track of what level you are working on.

Comment: Re-link: still not sure I understand. In the figure, it looks like the simplices are the highlighted parts (i.e. the edges). In example 4.7, the simplices are either vertices, edges or triangles. So in definition 4.17, when they write $\sigma\cup \{v\}$, do they mean that you take the edge $\sigma$, the vertex $\{v\}$ and the edges joining the vertices of $\sigma$ to $\{v\}$?

Comment: No, you take the edge $\sigma$, and then check if $\sigma\cup\{v\}$ (a triangle) is in $\Sigma$. If it is, then you keep the original edge $\sigma$ and if not, you get rid of it.

Comment: Also, the diagram doesn't make it clear, but the vertices are also part of the link. This is important to remember, as a link may be comprised of higher dim. simplices as well.

Comment: Oh ok, got it, thanks for your help

Comment: No problem. That Topology course was one of my favourites last year. Glad I could help.